# Express get/post method error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to learn node.js and I'm using express to have a form that should appear here: http://localhost:4000.

I started using "hello world" which worked well. Now with this second step I have a problem. If I select post method, it appears that I cannot GET on my browser. Also, if I select post method, the following appears:

> Username: undefined.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>    
  <form method="get" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Javascript

( post method is with comment)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

/*
 app.post('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Username: ' + req.body.username);
 });
*/

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Username: ' + req.query['username']);
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

I know that most probably the error is due to something simple; I'm trying to solve alone but until now I have found no solution.

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is? If you uncomment the POST route and make the form method POST, is it not working ?

Comment: And also, if you're going to use `req.body` you need a [**bodyParser**](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: As I put the code html with get method and on my js there is comment post method and is working get method so should be correct.

about bodyparser I should install with npm install body-parser then put var bodyParser = require('body-parser') on my jsn't it?